# Does Expression Engine 3.5+ work with PHP 7.4?

Tags: php

Hosting for the site is moving to a new server which will initially run PHP 7.2, but is slated to move to 7.4 soon. The documents show that 3.5+ will run on 7.2 but 7.4 is not mentioned.

Will EE 3.5+ run on 7.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the 3.x line supports PHP 7.4.  For what it's worth, the upgrade to 6.x is pretty simple from 3.x.  It would also put you on a major version that's LTS and as such will be supported for 5 more years.

https://expressionengine.com/support/version-support

Comment: Thank you Tom. This gives me some helpful insights.